# How well can Ada optimize static constant arrays?

Tags: optimization, constants, ada

Let's say I declare an array of constant values for use as a lookup table:

```
function Square(num : Integer) return Integer is
use Ada.Text_IO;
type LookupItemsRange is range 1..10;
type LookupTable is array(LookupItemsRange) of integer;
A : constant LookupTable := (2312,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10);
begin
    Sqr := A(1);
    Sqr := 2 * A(2);
    return Sqr;
end Square;
```

The LookupTable shouldn't use any space. The compiler should be able to substitute array access with the actual inlined values. At the highest optimization setting, here's what Ada yields:

```
_ada_square:
        li      a0,4                #,
        ret
```

I am planning on substituting a large amount of redundant MCU code with a cleaner lookup table implementation. Since the microcontroller's resources are constrained, I would like to avoid needless allocation and indexing.

Under what circumstances will Ada allocate the array or am I completely safe?

Comment: For "Under what circumstances..."; if the array index is unknowable at compile time (e.g. derived from user input, or like `Foo := A(random_number);`) it'd be difficult for any compiler (for any language) to avoid allocating the array; especially if there's no detectable pattern in the data (as there is in all but the first element in `(2312,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10)`).

Comment: But a constant array will be allocated in ROM, not RAM, and MCUs typically have a lot more ROM. My digital watch (in Ada) fits in under a kilobyte (LUTs and all) of program memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So for the Ada language specification, you won't get a guarantee for array objects.  Ada is starting to catch up to constexpr in the newest upcoming release (Ada2022), but will only be providing it's analogous property ([Static](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-9.html) in Ada) to expression functions (think of them analogous to constexpr functions but with slightly different limitations).

So if you don't mind relying on your compiler vendor, then the array will most likely work fine (but is not guaranteed).  If you want a more language supported guarantee on the optimization, then you will need to mimic the array using expression functions with the Static aspect set (in a recent compiler).  For a static input, a [static expression function](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-6-8.html#I4010) will give a static result (again Static in Ada, not static in c++, more like constexpr).

```ada
function Square return Integer is

    type Lookup_Items_Range is range 1..10;

    function A(Index : Lookup_Items_Range) return Integer is 
        (case Index is
            when 1 => 2312,
            when 2 => 2,
            when 3 => 3,
            when 4 => 4,
            when 5 => 5,
            when 6 => 6,
            when 7 => 7,
            when 8 => 8,
            when 9 => 9,
            when 10 => 10
         ) 
    with Static;

    Sqr : Integer;

begin

    Sqr := A(1);
    Sqr := 2 * A(2);
    return Sqr;
    
end Square;
```

It's slightly more verbose than using an array, but has the language backing, which is really important in certain embedded programming areas.  Note, most recent compilers will need a switch to enable this feature since it is so new, but they generally tell you that switch in the error message.  I tested on godbolt with GNAT 12.1 and it compiled with the correct switch.

Comment: Although a static expression function is likely to be compiled as desired in this context, *static* is used in the (unusual) Ada sense - determinable at compile time - so I think there can be no more guarantee for this approach than for the LUT (which, in my simple experiment, works as required even at `-O1`).

Answer (score 9):

1. This depends on your compiler and compiler options.
2. As you have demonstrated, whatever compiler you are using does an excellent job of optimization.
3. In [Ada Outperforms Assembly: A Case Study](https://www2.seas.gwu.edu/%7Eadagroup/sigada-website/lawlis.html), presented in 1992, an Ada (83) compiler produced faster code than assembler hand optimized by a team of experts. Presumably optimizers have gotten even better in the past 30+ years, so worrying about this kind of thing, in the absence of measurements showing otherwise, is A Waste of Time.

Comment: For traditional applications, you're indeed correct.  For memory-constrained MCUs where instruction timing is everything, it becomes critical. I am well aware of Ada's excellent optimization, but there are operations where the compiler will allocate the array and or generate instructions to access it.

Comment: Obviously the kind of optimization you're talking about can only happen if everything related to the array is static, and that's not true for a look-up table. The point is that if you can make things static, you can rely on the compiler to optimize them away; and when you can't, you can rely on the compiler to do a good job of optimizing what it can't optimize away.